# What username to use to connect over SSH to a domain joined Windows machine?

Tags: ssh

My Windows 11 Enterprise PC is domain joined and I log in using my work account in the format of `europe\myalias@domain.com`.

I installed the Open SSH server but no matter what I try, I cannot connect from my Mac:

```
user@MacBookAir Desktop % ssh myalias@192.168.178.30
myalias@192.168.178.30's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

- Using `europe\\myalias`: `Connection reset by 192.168.178.30 port 22`
- Using `myalias@domain.com`: `Permission denied`
- Using `europe\\myalias@domain.com`: `Connection reset`

What can I do to get this to work?

I'd also be fine using an SSH key, if that's an option. I have already generated key pairs on the Mac but then what?

Comment: I’ve got the same problem. On Windows in the *Event Viewer > Applications... > OpenSSH* I can see that when I try use single back-slash it is omitted and when I use double back-slash  (in order to escape it) both back-slashes shows-up in the log -- effectively making it impossible to pass just a single back-slash (as per my username as returned by `whoami` command).

Comment: the workaround was to ssh with the *admin@XX:XX:XX:XX* (fill in your IP,  you need to know the password ofc)

Answer (score 0):

Try ssh user@DOMAIN@host, i.e.

```
ssh myalias@domain.com@192.168.178.30
```

Comment: "Permission denied, please try again"

Comment: If password auth allowed on SSH server (may be only certificate auth)? Make sure you use domain alias.